# How should I store sensitive user data to an aws cognito attibute

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a web app that asks the user to enter a password for a third party service in order to connect to it. Ideally we would remember this password in order to avoid asking the user for the password on every login. Obviously, I do not want any access to the actual values of these passwords.

What is the best solution for this behaviour. Is this just simply a big no-no. Seems like there is probably a simple solution to this that I am just not aware of. I am considering using aws cognito for my user auth btw

Comment: If you have to present the password to the third party (do you?), how are you going to avoid being able to access its value? Does the third-party offer any kind of identity federation capability?

Comment: Are you able to use federation (OIDC, SAML, multi-step with services like Auth0 in the middle)? Then you don't need to store anything.